# Why does my program only output the last page of a multiple page scraping operation?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape multiple pages using beautifulsoup concept, but am getting only the last page results as output, please suggest the right way. Below is my code.

```
# For every page 

for page in range(0,8):
    # Make a get request
    response = get('http://nationalacademyhr.org/fellowsdirectory?page=0%2C{}' + format(page))
    # Pause the loop
    sleep(randint(8,15))
     # Monitor the requests
    requests += 1
    elapsed_time = time() - start_time
    print('Request:{}; Frequency: {} requests/s'.format(requests, requests/elapsed_time))
    clear_output(wait = True)

    html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    all_table_info = html_soup.find('table', class_ = "views-table cols-4")


    for name in all_table_info.find_all('div', 
           class_="views-field views-field-view"):
    names.append(name.text.replace("\n", " ")if name.text else None)


    for organization in all_table_info.find_all('td', 
           class_="views-field views-field-field-employer"):
    orgs.append(organization.text.strip() if organization.text else None)


    for year in all_table_info.find_all('td', 
           class_ = "views-field views-field-view-2"):
    Years.append(year.text.strip() if year.text else None)


    df = pd.DataFrame({'Name' : names, 'Org' : orgs, 'year' : Years })

    print (df)
```

Comment: Works for me, once indentation errors are fixed. What output are you seeing?

Comment: yeah it is working but its giving the output of lastpage first,and then the first page is repeating multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typing error: a plus instead of a dot. You need `'http://nati...ge=0%2C{}'.format(page)`,
but you wrote
`'http://nati...ge=0%2C{}' + format(page)`

URLs having braces before the page number end up at the same page.

EDIT:

If I was not clear, you need just change the line

`response = get('http://nationalacademyhr.org/fellowsdirectory?page=0%2C{}' + format(page))`

to

`response = get('http://nationalacademyhr.org/fellowsdirectory?page=0%2C{}'.format(page))`

In the first case the resulting URL contains also the substring '{}', which causes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: there are 9 pages on the site identified by `page=0,0` through to `page=0,8`. Your loop should use `range(9)`. Or, even better, load the first page then get the URL for the next page using the `next` link. Iterate over all the page by following the `next` link until there is no `next` link on the page.

---

Further to [xhancar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47035980/21945) which identifies the problem, a better way is to avoid string operations when building URLs, and instead let `requests` construct the URL query string for you:

```
for page in range(9):
    params = {'page': '0,{}'.format(page)}
    response = get('http://nationalacademyhr.org/fellowsdirectory', params=params)
```

The [`params`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls) parameter is passed to `requests.get()` which adds the values to the URL query string. The query parameters will be properly encoded, e.g. the `,` replaced with `%2C`.